# Filter on computed property not returning all the elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I did a filter to display colours based in a selected model type. So by example if type x1 is display then I will return all the colours that contain this model .See structure example below:

```
      {
        "colorName": "anthrazitbraunmetallic ",
        "colourHex": {
          "hex": "#2D2829"
        },
        "id": "58963584",
        "relatedModels": [
          {
            "id": "48354230",
            "modelName": "typex1"
          },
          {
            "id": "48355531",
            "modelName": "txpex3"
          },
          {
            "id": "48355536",
            "modelName": "typex5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "colorName": "aquablaumetallic",
        "colourHex": {
          "hex": "#021546"
        },
        "id": "58963586",
        "relatedModels": [
          {
            "id": "48355512",
            "modelName": "typex0"
          },
          {
            "id": "48354230",
            "modelName": "typex1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "colorName": "arenarotmetallic ",
        "colourHex": {
          "hex": "#450916"
        },
        "id": "58964875",
        "relatedModels": [
          {
            "id": "48355531",
            "modelName": "typex3"
          },
          {
            "id": "48355536",
            "modelName": "typex5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "colorName": "argusbraunmetallic",
        "colourHex": {
          "hex": "#322C2C"
        },
        "id": "58965372",
        "relatedModels": [
          {
            "id": "48355540",
            "modelName": "typex4"
          }
        ]
      },
```

The filter is working and I have no errors however I noticed something, is not returning all the registers. Currently I am working with a headless and I also have the amount of colours per model, and for example for the "type x3", based on the system filters and the excel registers, but I'm only getting 69 I suppose to get 112 colours, and I have the same behaviour with all the colours, I'm only getting around the half of the colours that I supposed too. And I was wondering if is something related with my filter:

```
colorByModel() {
    var objectColours = this.colours.allCatalogColours;
    const result = objectColours.filter((item) => {
      return (
        item.relatedModels.findIndex((m) => m.modelName == this.$route.matched[0].name) >
        -1
      );
   
    });
    return result;

  },
```

I was wondering if is related with the findIndex function, I also tried with  "find" but with both I have the same result, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Do you have an example of a color that gets removed even though it is not supposed to be removed?

Comment: Hello Emil, thank you for you answer, also that's a very interesting question and gave me the hint, I did review it and I realised that all colours after the register #100 are not being show, but then based in the documentation of the CMS, I only can query max 100 registers, that's why when filtering I only find colours that under the first 100 registers contains a specific model. How I will solve it, have no idea will try to figure out, thank you again.

Comment: It varies between different API:s, but you can most likely write something like "&page=1" in the URL, to define that you want page 1 (the page you are currently getting) or "&page=2" to get page 2, etc. You should also get information (meta data) on how many pages there are (it's probably named something like "total_pages"). So you need to fetch all the pages before you can filter anything. How you do that depends heavily on what the API looks like and how you are fetching the data.